# Is there a theorem of prominent Russian mathematicians that played an important role in the development of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, mathematics

I once attended a seminar in which a statement answering the question asked above was answered in the affirmative.

I do not recall further specifics, however.

Comment: better suited for mathematics.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

A search on Google Scholar yielded

[NeuralComputation 1991 article](https://direct.mit.edu/neco/article/3/4/617/5612/Kolmogorov-s-Theorem-Is-Relevant)

That is

> Kolmogorov's Theorem Is Relevant
>
> Abstract We show that Kolmogorov's theorem on representations of
> continuous functions of n-variables by sums and superpositions of
> continuous functions of one variable is relevant in the context of
> neural networks. We give a version of this theorem with all of the
> one-variable functions approximated arbitrarily well by linear
> combinations of compositions of affine functions with some given
> sigmoidal function. We derive an upper estimate of the number of
> hidden units."

This theorem of Kolmogorov is surely the one referred to in the seminar I attended. But I somewhat erred I first thought in using the plural of mathematician.

But then I see the terminology

"Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem (or superposition theorem)" is also employed.

Wikipedia gives the following references:

> Andrey Kolmogorov, "On the representation of continuous functions of
> several variables by superpositions of continuous functions of a
> smaller number of variables", Proceedings of the USSR Academy of
> Sciences, 108 (1956), pp. 179–182; English translation: Amer. Math.
> Soc. Transl., 17 (1961), pp. 369–373.
>
> Vladimir Arnold, "On functions
> of three variables", Proceedings of the USSR Academy of Sciences, 114
> (1957), pp. 679–681; English translation: Amer. Math. Soc. Transl., 28
> (1963), pp. 51–54.